ITextpdf library erros are logged with severity INFO
I'm stucked with issue that errors thrown from itext library for some reason are logged with severity INFO in logs.
Example of error logged with severity INFO:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: {FILE} (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:180) ~[na:na]
    at com.itextpdf.io.util.UrlUtil.getInputStreamOfFinalConnection(UrlUtil.java:154) ~[io-7.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.resolver.resource.DefaultResourceRetriever.getInputStreamByUrl(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:94) ~[styled-xml-parser-7.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.resolver.resource.DefaultResourceRetriever.getByteArrayByUrl(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:105) ~[styled-xml-parser-7.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.resolver.resource.ResourceResolver.retrieveBytesFromResource(ResourceResolver.java:199) ~[styled-xml-parser-7.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.createFont(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:490) ~[html2pdf-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.addFontFaceFonts(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:451) ~[html2pdf-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:253) ~[html2pdf-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:78) ~[html2pdf-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:331) ~[html2pdf-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:141) ~[html2pdf-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.extendedConvertExplodedTemplateImpl(PdfProducer.java:638) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.convertExplodedTemplateReflection(PdfProducer.java:490) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.convertExplodedTemplate(PdfProducer.java:473) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.convertAndCleanUpExplodedTemplate(PdfProducer.java:453) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.extendedConvertTemplateFromPackage(PdfProducer.java:240) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.convertTemplateFromPackage(PdfProducer.java:234) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer.convertTemplateFromPackage(PdfProducer.java:217) ~[sdk-java-2.5.8.jar:na]

Also, I can see that such code inside a library mapped to severity INFO for some reason:
 logger.error(MessageFormatUtil.format("Unable to retrieve stream with given base URI ({0}) and source path ({1})", new Object[]{this.uriResolver.getBaseUri(), src}), var4);

How can I configure a library logging to show errors as erros in spring boot?
